# What is the cause of "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, configuration, bug, router

As a Magento developer I have faced this problem tons of times, I know it is a misconfiguration problem when it occurs some modules are not loaded, neither their routers, causing the error. Most of the times it is solved with no action, other times you may flush the cache

I've read multiple posts about this, trying to debug placing some extra code in Magento core Front controller `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`, but at the end this only shows which module routers are missing, not **why** they are not being loaded. Every time it occurs I try to look which URLs are giving the error, but this is useless information, same as the code trace. It's always the same

Maybe it is caused by module conflicts? Maybe it is some cron task doing something wrong? Maybe some wrong code in older Magento versions? The thing is this problem does not occur since 1.7 version (or if it occurs then it is totally sporadic). I have found some code differences in the main flow, such as

```
Mage::register('application_params', $params);
```

In run() method of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php`, or the

```
$this->_shouldSkipProcessModulesUpdates()
```

check in **_initModules()** method...

I want to believe there should be someone who has definitively found the cause. Any tips?

Comment: Have you referenced this? https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix

Comment: The poster of that article was able to fix their issue by overriding `Mage_Core_Model_Config` and forcing `$_useCache = false`

Comment: After reading the whole article, I think you should post that as the right answer to my question, so other users could read it. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you were experiencing a Magento configuration bug.

There is an excellent write-up with solution [here](https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix).

In that article the author was able to rectify the bug by overriding `Mage_Core_Model_Config` and forcing `$_useCache = false` when regenerating the config.

Comment: Damnit! I never get to reap the rep for that article, other people always link to it first ;)

Comment: Very nice writeup @LukeRodgers!

Comment: I'd just like to comment and say that Magento have accepted this as a fix to the problem with SUPEE-4755

https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#update-good-news-a-patch-from-magento

Comment: I've also added another patch. Not quite as nice, but discussed here. https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#update-2-further-improvements

Comment: I'm facing this issue in Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0. It should be fixed right because it's old issue?

Comment: I've added Magento2 tag to question

Answer (score 7):

Check the Magento configuration settings **Default No-route URL** at

```
System > Configurations > Web > Default Pages
```

. It should be set the default value **cms/index/noRoute**. Check the particular store value as well whether it default value has been overwritten here. Magento can go into an infinite loop till it hits the 100 iterations limit if it is not set properly.

If you use [Magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun), run this command.

```
magerun config:set cms/index/noRoute no-route
```

I have found the solution here, this is was the issue in my case. You can check the URL for other options.

https://merchantprotocol.com/506/solved-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/

Comment: If I execute ./n98-magerun.phar config:get no-route then I get Couldn't find a config value for "no-route", and the config entry does not even exist, are you sure with your answer?

Comment: @Black you are doing it wrong. the console get method requires the path - so your command should be - \n
"n98-magerun.phar config:get cms/index/noRoute" \n
Please check help option by running "n98-magerun.phar config:get --help"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redis, simply restart Redis server