# Solved: Magento site crashes every day, after emptying /var/cache/ works fine

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

My magento site crashes daily. It comes back online after emptying the cache folder. The crash seems to be happening because the page.xml file changes the external files - js, css, images are all pointed to the default theme, whereas I use a custom theme. Could this be because of file permissions? Permissions for var and cache folder is 755.

Update: The problem is the cache file getting corrupted and the error I was getting was Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Comment: Do you have any cdn server or cloudflare enable??

Comment: No not at the moment.

Comment: is there something in your logs or reports? There should be an error message.

Comment: Checked the error logs, from the recent crash timeline this is the error I got.PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /home/storesolanki/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43.  But I'm not using captcha on the site .

Comment: @Anith update the question with that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [stackoverflow link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69068/what-is-the-cause-of-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-erro)  and installed this patch available on [github](https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix) to resolve the issue