# How to Fix - Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento-1.9, error, controllers

I know there is a lot written about this kind of error but I haven't been able to fix it yet. Here is the Report error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:446:"#0 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(154): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(189): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /home/xxxx/public_html/mx/index.php(66): Mage::run('mx', 'store')
#4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/mx/review/product/post/id/25/";s:11:"script_name";s:13:"/mx/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"mx";}
```

I found this [[Fix It Series] Magento Error: Front Controller Reached 100 router Match Iterations](https://www.tigren.com/front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/)

and I added the debug code to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` and here's what I got in system.log:

```
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 WARN (4): Honeypot Input filled. Aborted.
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 99
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Request: [path_info=/etreviewnotify/product/post/id/25/][module=honeyspam][action=index][controller=error][controller_module=Hackathon_HoneySpam][route=hackathon_honeyspam]
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 WARN (4): Honeypot Input filled. Aborted.
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Matched by "standard" router, class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
2018-03-22T18:29:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): - Iteration 100
```

How can I fix this? The debug says there is an `[controller=error]` but I'm still stuck on this.

Comment: Maybe helpfull: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69068/what-is-the-cause-of-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-erro

Answer (score 0):

I changed `Config.php` at: `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` with the one from `https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` I believe that fixed it, I've been clicking everywhere and it seems fixed. Thanks sv3n